# How to load another process' window as a child window?

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi

I have an executable called A.exe (say it is cmd.exe). I want to launch it (and also I want multiple instances of it) inside another window (that is I have to create) like,

[image]

How can I create such a window (program) using win32 or MFC ? Or this isn't possible ? Thank you.....

regards,

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: oh...my initial guess was that... but I'm wondering whether there is a possibility to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Windows' Calculator in my C# Win Application  ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113755/open-windows-calculator-in-my-c-win-application)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3459874/103167 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23160955/103167

Comment: Related: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by hooking window creation and re-directing all creations to be children of the parent process.  AFAIK (And I'll probably get told otherwise) window handles are global so you can descend from ANY window, including windows in other processes.

Comment: Hey ! thanks for the answer. Could you please direct me to an article or example ? It would be really.... helpful.