# Java Window as Child Form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

is it possible to add an instance of a java application as a child form a .NET Form?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very strange thing to want. What's the motivation here? Why does the Java application have to be a child of a .NET application? Why can't you just run two applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is. A Java program will have to run in its own process. A window from one process cannot be the child of a window of another process.

EDIT: Apparently I was wrong, it *is* possible to have a window from one process be a child of a window from another process, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113755/open-windows-calculator-in-my-c-sharp-win-application)

It *might* work with Java, depending on how the Java GUI framework the application uses works with Windows controls. The Windows Spy can help you figure out a little more about your Java application.

Comment: I've seen some tutorials about the windows calculator as child window of a .net form. But that doens't work with a java window. :/

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy and straightforward way todo that, at least that I'm aware of. One of possible solutions could be to make from your `Java` application an `Applet` and recall it inside embedded in Windows Form `WebBrowser`   control. After you need to care about communication between your application and applet.

Some hints can find [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/0a377a2e-4e23-44d0-8660-ff35fd3c75c4)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats not possible because the Java application is not written by me. So i have no chance to put it into an applet. But the Application is a Command Line windows, so is it possible to get the output? Like you can do it with a standard command line application? Thanks

Comment: If the application written in `Java` produces some *expected* output and you can manipulate it in reasonable way for *your* application, it's the way to go. Do not embed anything, but run that `Java` app like a separate exe. An example how to read can find [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput)